# estou tendo problemas em meu angular angular , quando vou da um npm start ele da essa mensagem

Tags: angular, angular-material

> This likely means that the library (@angular/material/snack-bar) which declares MatSnackBar has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is
> available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

esta assim meus imports

> app.module.ts

````
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/template/header/header.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { FooterComponent } from './components/template/footer/footer.component';
import { NavComponent } from './components/template/nav/nav.component'

import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav'
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card'
import { MatListModule } from '@angular/material/list';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatSnackBar } from '@angular/material/snack-bar'
import { ProductCrudComponent } from './views/product-crud/product-crud.component';
import { ProductCreateComponent } from './components/products/product-create/product-create.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './views/home/home.component'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    NavComponent,
    ProductCrudComponent,
    ProductCreateComponent,
    HomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatListModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSnackBar
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }```
````

Comment: eu ja fiz muitas coisas, ja atualizei o @angular/material, tentei atualizar a ivy, o angular e ainda copiei src do meu projeto e removi a pasta em que estou fazendo o angular  e troquei o src do novo projeto em angular, ja tentei remover o node_modules e reinstalar e contina dando esse proplema

Comment: Verifica no seu package.json a versão do seu @angular/material se está de acordo com a versão do angular instalada no seu projeto.

Comment: Eé, eu vi a versão e estava desatualizada, obr

Answer (score -2):

Tente adicionar em package.json
"scripts": {
**"postinstall": "ngcc"**
}

Answer (score -2):

Tente colocar Module após a MatSnackBar (isso no app.module.ts), como está abaixo:

```
import { MatSnackBarModule } from '@angular/material/snack-bar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
    MatSnackBarModule
  ],
```